# how to open a local file with an editor running on a remote server

Tags: ssh

I can run a program on a remote server like

```
ssh -Y me@192.168.1.100 gvim
```

However gvim can only see files on the remote server.
Is it possible to run a program from a remote server, but have it work on local files?

Answer (score 0):

I would just `scp` the local file to the remote server first.

Of course installing gvim on the local system would likely work better.

Answer (score 0):

Your local machine must be running ssh, then you can do

```
localusername@localmachine: ssh username@server -R 10000:localmachine:22
username@server: cd /var
username@server: sshfs -p 10000 -o idmap=user,nonempty \
                 localusername@127.0.0.1:~/mywwwdevelstuff www
```

Taken from https://superuser.com/a/918708/25609

Answer (score 0):

You can run a program on the remote machine like this:
`ssh -t <user>@<remote host> '<program to execute with full path and arguments>'`

```
     -t      Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary
             screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g.
             when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t options force tty allocation,
             even if ssh has no local tty.
```